# Why is IntelliJ not compiling TypeScript on save?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, file-watcher

The TypeScript plugin is installed for IntelliJ IDEA (v2020.1 EAP), but TypeScript files are not being compiled when I save them, despite having "Recompile on changes" checked:

[image]

I can manually run `tsc -w`, and everything compiles. Do I need to add a file watcher or something? Feels wrong, because the IDE knows what files I touched.

Comment: Does it happen in any project? Are there any errors in TS tool window console?

Comment: I have the same issue in IntelliJ 2019.03. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but it seems to be working now (using IntelliJ 2019.03).

- I unchecked all "TypeScript Language Service" options, changed the TypeScript compiler from "Bundled" to a locally installed one, and then re-checked the "TypeScript Language Service" options. Also I changed compile scope to "All Places".
- I started the compilation from the TypeScript Tool Window using "Compile All" instead of the tsconfig.json file.
- I restarted the TypeScript Service using the corresponding button in the  TypeScript Tool Window.

I am unsure which of these actions actually fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and resolved it with the help of IntelliJ's support. In my case, the project files were corrupted. I used these steps to delete and re-create the `.idea` folder:

1. Delete the `.idea` folder
2. Close the project
3. Remove it from **Recent** projects list
4. Shut down the IDE
5. Start the IDE
6. Open the project root folder with **File** > **Open**